# How to repeat a function in php for every element in an array without it timing out

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, csv, timeout

I have a function that will take an id and with that find out other information in the database relating to it spread among 3 tables.  It then compares this to a csv file which at most times is cpu intensive.  Running this once with one id takes approx 8 to 10 sec at most but I have been asked to have it run automatically across a varing number of ids in the database.  To do this I created an array of the ids that match the criteria in the database at any point and then run a 'while' statement to repeat the function for each element in the array but it gets as far as maybe 4 of them and I get the following error:

> Server error!
>
> The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete
>   your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in
>   a CGI script.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 500

I'll admit that my code could be much much cleaner as I'm still learning as I go but the real bottle neck appears to be reading the csv which is a report which size changes each day.  I have tried different combinations and the best result is (please don't chastise me for this as I know it is stupid but the other ways haven't works as of yet) to run the code as follows:

```
$eventArray = eventArray($venueId);
$totalEvents = count($eventArray);

for($i=0; $i<$totalEvents; $i++)
    {
        $eventId = $eventArray[$i];
        echo $eventId;
        echo $datename = getEventDetails($eventId, $zone);
            // date of event
        echo $eventDate = $datename['eventDate'];
            // vs team
        echo $eventName = $datename['eventName'];

        $file_handle = fopen("data/rohm/sales/today.csv", "r");
        while (!feof($file_handle) )
            {
                $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 200);
                include('finance_logic.php');
            }
        fclose($file_handle);
    }
```

Yes, it is repeating the reading of the csv every time but I couldn't get it to function at all any other way so if this is the issue I would really appreciate some guidence on dealing with the csv better.  Incase it is relevent the code it 'finance_logic.php' is listed below:

```
if($line_of_text[0] == "Event: $eventName ")
{
    $f = 1;
    $ticketTotalSet = "no";
    $killSet = 'no';
    // default totals zero
    $totalHolds = 0;
    $totalKills = 0;
    $ticketSold = 0;
    $ticketPrice = 0;
    $totalCap = 0;
}
if($f == 1 && $line_of_text[0] == "$eventDate")
    {
        $f = 2;
    }
    if($f == 2 && $line_of_text[0] == "Holds")
        {
            $f = 3;
            while($line_of_text[$col] !== "Face Value Amt")
                {
                    $col++;
                }
        }
        if($f == 3 && $line_of_text[0] !== "Face Value Amt")
            {
                if($f == 3 && $line_of_text[0] == "*: Kill")
                    {
                        $totalKills = $line_of_text[$col];
                    }
                $holdsArray[] = $line_of_text[$col];
            }
        if($f == 3 && $line_of_text[0] == "--")
            {
                $f = 4;
            }
            if($f == 4 && $line_of_text[0] == "Capacity")
                {
                    $totalCap = $line_of_text[$col];
                    $f = 5;
                }   
                if($f == 5 && $line_of_text[0] == "Abbreviated Performance Totals")
                    {
                        $f = 6;
                    }
                    if($f == 6 && $line_of_text[0] == "$eventName")
                        {
                            // change when 1 ticket exists
                            $ticketTotalSet = "yes";
                            // set season tickets
                            include("financial/seasontickets/$orgShortName.php");
                            // all non season are single tickets
                            if(!isset($category))
                                {
                                    $category = 'single';
                                }
                            $ticketName = $line_of_text[2];
                            $ticketSold = $line_of_text[3];
                            $ticketPrice = $line_of_text[4];
                            addTicketType($eventId, $ticketName, $category, $ticketSold, $ticketPrice);
                            unset($category);
                        }
                        if($f == 6 && $ticketTotalSet == "yes" && $line_of_text[0] !== "$eventName")
                            {
                                $totalHolds = (array_sum($holdsArray) - $totalKills);
                                // add cap, holds and kills
                                addKillsHoldsCap($eventId, $totalCap, $eventId, $totalHolds, $totalKills);
                                // reset everything
                                $f = 0;
                                $ticketTotalSet = "no";
                                echo "$eventName updated!";
                            }
```

Thanks in advance!

p.s. The reason the report is called each time is so that the 'eventName' and 'eventDate' are searched for with the 'finance_logic.php'.  Obviously if this was set with all event names and dates already it would take one search of the report to find them all but I'm not sure how I could do this dynamically.  Any suggestions would be welcome as I'm sure there is something out there that I just haven't learnt yet.

Comment: What you have posted is a _browser_ error message. Try turning off any "friendly" error messages in your browser settings and try again, it should display the actual error that came from the webserver, to see if it is indeed an execution timeout. You can also check your webserver's error log. Execution time limit can be controlled via [`set_time_limit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

Comment: The error 500 can also be given in a fastcgi situation when the PHP script takes longer then fastcgi allows. In this case the timeout of fastcgi has to be increased. However it would be better to read the CSV file only ones and iterate over the events for each line of the CVS. However the code is hard to rework. Things would get much easier if you used an actual function instead of the horific include('finance_logic.php'); within the while loop. Functions much better isolate the code making it easier to understand and to get right.

Comment: Thanks lanzz, I'll check this out.  And Eelke, the code in the include changes dramatically depending on the report and person using it so I found that the easiest way and less problematic was in this format.  What makes it horrific as opposed to a function?  is it only the fact that it is less easy to understand or some functional reason?

Comment: also, eelke.  I agree that it isn't advisable to read the report each time but as you can see I am trying to find spicific sections of it each time and I'm not sure how I would do it otherwise.  I need to check if particular settings are met but needs to be dynamic.  Otherwise I would just have the search set for each array element and it would search for each the first time around.  As I need to have it change each time would you know how I can have this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some heavy script i use with localhost sometimes and if i don't add anything they will just time out.

A simple solution is to limit the number of execution of your function, then reload the page, then restart where you stopped.

Comment: I was attempting to do this but wasn't able to get it to work correctly.  How would you suggest getting this to work?

Comment: Well, you could manage to limit the execution of the FOR by adding a flag. For exemple, when $i = 5, you reload the page with a POST/GET value $i = 5 and then, you restart the FOR from $i = 5 and not $i = 0.

Comment: hmm, I'm annoyed I didn't think of that.  I'll give it a go.

Comment: I just did this.  Was more straight forward.  Still getting an error every so often though.  Looking into it but thanks.